# Bounded sequence in a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a Banach space in $\mathbb{K}$ and $(x_n)$ a sequence in $X$, and let $f$ be any function in $X^*$ (the dual space of $X$) such that the sequence $(f(x_n))$ is bounded.

I am trying to prove that in this case, the sequence $(||x_n||_X)$ is bounded.

I have managed to prove than for a given integer $n$, $||x_n||_X=||\psi_{x_n} ||$, where $\psi$ is a function defined on $X^*$ with values in $\mathbb{K}$ defined by $\psi_{x_n}(f)=f(x_n)$. So if the sequence $(f(x_n))$ is bounded, then so is 
$(\psi_{x_n}(f))$. Can we conclude that this implies that $||\psi_{x_n} ||$ (and therefore $||x_n||_X$) is bounded?

My intuition tells me it does, as $||\psi_{x_n} ||=\sup\limits_{f\neq0}\{\frac{||\psi_{x_n}(f)||}{||f||}\}$, but I am not sure since $\psi_{x_n}$ is a function while $(\psi_{x_n})$ is a sequence (of functions..).

Comment: Is $f$ continuous, or just linear? If it is continuous, then the answer is easy, just pull out the norm of $x_n$ from $f$ and use the fact that $f$ is bounded in the unit ball.

Comment: @dafinguzman: unfortunately $f$ is only linear and bounded.

Comment: bounded linear implies continuous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\hat x_n \in X^{**}$ be defined by

$$ \hat x_n (f) = f(x_n),\ \ \ \forall f\in X^*.$$

Then the condition imply

$$\sup_{n\in \mathbb N} |\hat x_n (f)| < \infty$$

for all $f$. The [uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Theorem) implies that

$$\sup_{n\in \mathbb N} \|\hat x_n\|_{X^{**}} <\infty,$$

which is just the same as

$$\sup_{n\in \mathbb N} \|x_n\|_{X} <\infty$$

as $\|x_n\| = \|\hat x_n\|$.